# How to Call Json City in Ajax?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Their are many examples on google but they are not helpful,
i'm getting this error VM169:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0   at JSON.parse ()

here 0 is GET and POST 
1 is Json in jquery file

```
$("#stateID").change(function(){
            var stateID= $(this).val();
            if(stateID != ""){
                var stateJson=xAjaxCall("ajax/state-city-json/"+stateID,null,0,1);
                if(stateJson != null && !xIsEmptyJSON(stateJson)){
                    xBindJSONtoCombo(stateJson, $("#cityID"));
                }
            }
        });
```

My controller

```
@ResponseBody          //get State-city-json
    @RequestMapping(value="/ajax/state-city-json/{stateID}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getStateJson(@PathVariable("stateID") int stateID){
        System.out.println("Ajax call city");
        return JSONObject.toJSONString(userRegistrationCommonService.getCityMap(stateID));
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the API you're querying is returning JSON? Opening with a bracket suggests you're receiving XML. What happens if you curl the endpoint?

Comment: It is only displaying first state cities in list, for example if I have state[A,B,C] in state table and city[A1,A2,B1,B2C1,C2] i'm only getting [A1,A2] cities with error mentioned above